# How to transfer more files rather than just one using python?

Tags: python, file-transfer

I made a file transferrer and the problem is that out of unknown reason it lets me only send one file... When I try the second time the program works fine, but the file doesn't show up in directory. It would mean a lot to me if someone helped me out.

Code for sender:

```
import os
import shutil
import socket
import time

# Creating a socket.
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
sock.bind((socket.gethostname(), 22222))
sock.listen(5)
print("Host Name: ", sock.getsockname())

# Accepting the connection.
client, addr = sock.accept()

original = ""
print("When you want to stop with file uploading type -> STOP <-")
while (1):
    original = input(str("Filepath:"))
    if (original!="STOP"):
        filename = os.path.basename(original)
        target = r'C:\Users\Gasper\Desktop\transfer\filename'
        path = target.replace('filename', filename)
        new_file = shutil.copy(original, path)

        # Getting file details.
        file_name = filename
        file_size = os.path.getsize(file_name)

        # Sending file_name and detail.
        client.send(file_name.encode())
        client.send(str(file_size).encode())

        # Opening file and sending data.
        with open(file_name, "rb") as file:
            c = 0

            # Running loop while c != file_size.
            while c <= file_size:
                data = file.read(1024)
                if not data:
                    break
                client.sendall(data)
                c += len(data)

        os.remove(filename)
    else:
        break

print("File Transfer Complete!")
input("Press enter to exit...")

# Closing the socket.
sock.close()
```

Code for receiver:

```
    import socket
import time

host = input("Host Name: ")
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

# Trying to connect to socket.
try:
    sock.connect((host, 22222))
    print("Connected Successfully")
except:
    print("Unable to connect")
    exit(0)

# Send file details.
file_name = sock.recv(100).decode()
file_size = sock.recv(100).decode()

# Opening and reading file.
with open("./rec/" + file_name, "wb") as file:
    c = 0
    # Starting the time capture.
    start_time = time.time()

    # Running the loop while file is recieved.
    while c <= int(file_size):
        data = sock.recv(1024)
        if not data:
            break
        file.write(data)
        c += len(data)

    # Ending the time capture.
    end_time = time.time()

print("File transfer Complete!")

input("Press enter to exit...")
# Closing the socket.
sock.close()
```

Example:

Filepath: `C\Users\Admin\Desktop\Directory\File1.txt`(I put in the first file path and it transfers successfully)

Filepath: `C\Users\Admin\Desktop\Directory\File2.txt`(I put in the second file path and it doesnt transfer at all)

Comment: Your client reads until end-of-stream, so it can only receive one file at a time. You need a different protocol, one that allows your client to know when one file has ended and the next one begins.

Comment: encapsulate the file in your own protocol and packetize it. for example if the first byte tells what to expect and the next 4 tell how many bytes that item is, you could encapsulate file info as a starting packet, the expected file contents as middle packets, and some end of file packet to tell that the file is done.